# query to find qualified rows in subsets

Tags: sql

I have a table of different versions of files.  All the versions of a file should be marked deleted except for the last one.

```
 file_key | path  | version | is_deleted 
----------+-------+---------+------------
        1 | foo/1 |       1 | f       <=== wrong
        2 | foo/1 |       2 | f       <=== wrong
        3 | foo/1 |       3 | f
        4 | bar/2 |       1 | t
        5 | bar/2 |       2 | t
        6 | bar/2 |       3 | f
```

I'm looking for a query to find those first two rows and mark them `is_deleted`.  I've stumbled around with some self-joins and only ended up with combinatorials, and a "with" CTE was starting to look infinitely recursive.

Is there a sql solution for this, or should I just write a cursor?

Comment: Which RDBMS (SQL Flavor)?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I doubt that, but it might depend on which database technology is in use.

Comment: @jpmc26 you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (file_key INT, [Path] VARCHAR(10),[Version] INT, is_deleted CHAR(1))
INSERT INTO @t
VALUES 
(1,'foo/1',1,'f'), (2,'foo/1',2,'f'),(3,'foo/1',3,'f'),
(4,'bar/2',1,'t'),(5,'bar/2',2,'t'),(5,'bar/2',3,'f')
```

**Query** (For Sql-Server)

```
;WITH LatestVersions
AS
  (
   SELECT *, rn = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Path] ORDER BY [Version] DESC)
   FROM @t
  )
UPDATE LatestVersions
SET is_deleted =  't'
FROM LatestVersions
WHERE rn > 1
```

**Result Set**

```
╔══════════╦═══════╦═════════╦════════════╗
║ file_key ║ Path  ║ Version ║ is_deleted ║
╠══════════╬═══════╬═════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ foo/1 ║       1 ║ t          ║
║        2 ║ foo/1 ║       2 ║ t          ║
║        3 ║ foo/1 ║       3 ║ f          ║
║        4 ║ bar/2 ║       1 ║ t          ║
║        5 ║ bar/2 ║       2 ║ t          ║
║        5 ║ bar/2 ║       3 ║ f          ║
╚══════════╩═══════╩═════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Just state somewhere that you used `SQL Server` syntax.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Here's the postgres version (where the table is called "article_files")

 `WITH latest_versions
 AS
  (
   SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Path ORDER BY Version DESC) as rn
   FROM article_files
  )
 UPDATE article_files
 SET is_deleted =  't'
 FROM latest_versions
 WHERE rn > 1`

Comment: @KevinG. dont know anything about `postgres` but thanks for sharing :) its not much different from sql server though.